# chmod: WARNING: can't change home

Tags: solaris-10

```
# chmod 755 home
chmod: WARNING: can't change home
#
```

after I installed solaris 10, /home isn't writeable by anyone, when I try and change the permissionss as root, I get the above error.

Edit: Original permission were set to 777

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to change `/home` permission, and especially setting them to `0777` would introduce a major security vulnerability.

You probably want to create a regular home directory for a new user. By default, Solaris is configured to have that directory stored on a shared location automounted by multiple OS instances with NFS. `/home` is the mount point for these directories while on the server hosting the directories, which might be the same one, the actual directories are usually stored under `/export/home/`.

You might either let this mechanism preconfigured and use `/export/home` instead as base directory for your new users or permanently disable the automounter for the home directories only.

The latter is done by commenting out the line that reads

```
/home auto_home -nobrowse
```

in the `/etc/auto_master` configuration file. Then restart the automounter service:

```
svcadm restart autofs
```

Make sure `/home` permissions are the original ones: `dr-xr-xr-x` and you are done.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply, which reminds me of this [comic](http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2015/11/03/guys-who-overdo-it-on-stackoverflow/) :) I was trying to set it to 755 myself, the original poster from which I took the question was trying to set it to 777, which I agree is a security concern.

Comment: In your original question, the permissions were 777. In any case, there is no much point changing the owner permissions when the owner is root. Root isn't subject to permissions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

From: http://www.unix.com/solaris/38623-solaris-10-home.html

Before doing chmod try as root or with sudo:

```
# /usr/sbin/svcadm disable -t autofs
```

Comment: That's a doomed approach.